# How to unlock broken iPhone 5c?

Tags: unlock, iphone

I would like to import photos from an iPhone 5c.
When I connect the iPhone to the PC with a USB cable the PC says the iPhone is locked.

I don't know how to unlock it and even if I did, I can't: half of the screen looks like a matrix and the Home button is gone.

I've been using Siri to send texts and make calls but can only do that when the phone is charging.

How can I unlock the iPhone or iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "I don't know how to unlock it and even if I did, I can't: half of the screen looks like a matrix" ?

Do you mean you actually **do know how to unlock it** but can't because the screen is damaged? Or do you mean you can't because you've forgotten your passcode? Or do you mean something else?

We may be able to help if you provide full details of your situation and what you've already tried.

For example, have you tried any of the following:

1. Restarting your device by holding down both the power button and pressing down on where the home button should be for at least 10 secs until the Apple logo appears?
2. Double tapping on the slider to see what happens?
3. Connecting your device to your computer **after** launching iTunes?
4. Connecting your device to your computer and **running** your photo software to see if you can transfer your photos?

Also, is your device set up to use photo stream on iCloud? If so, your photos may already be accessible via iCloud from another device, so you may not need to transfer them from the iPhone.

Please provide as much info as you can.